# Monotone solutions of the heat equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the heat equation
$$u_t - a\Delta u = f$$ in a bounded domain
with some boundary conditions, e.g. Robin BCs, and the initial condition $u|_{t=0}=u_0$.

Are there some results of the following type? If the initial function $u_0$ is a supersolution of the elliptic equation
$$-a\Delta u = f$$ then the solution of the heat equation monotonically decreases in time for all $x$.

I've found an article about monotone methods by Sattinger but it concerns strong solutions. Do you know references concerning weak solutions?

Comment: If $a$ and $f$ are any good, then weak solutions are also strong solutions.

Comment: @NormalHuman Nevertheless I need proof for weak solutions.